# in ASPX/VB using a gridview, how do I allow a checkbox on the row to be checked/unchecked without hitting some edit button?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm on an extreme time crunch, and its been years since doing any of this.  I'm trying to take an old project, and enable a checkbox within the gridview.

My aspx gridview is:

```
                <asp:GridView ID="grdReg" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True" CssClass="table table-hover" GridLines="None">
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="thead-dark" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="" DataField="pkID" ReadOnly="True"></asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="YourID" DataField="yourID" ReadOnly="True"></asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="fullname" ReadOnly="True"></asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Program" DataField="program" ReadOnly="True"></asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Status" DataField="eStatus" ReadOnly="True"></asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Recen" DataField="recent" ReadOnly="True"></asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Enabled?" DataField="enabled" ReadOnly="False"></asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Now - the last column "Enabled?" is bound to a SQL Server bit field.  Right now, when you display the aspx page - it shows 'True' or 'False' or blank if null.

Right now, I don't care if the field is a checkbox or shows the True/False - but when you click on it, I want it to toggle from T -> F or checked to unchecked.  It's been too long since I've been in VB, and I need a simple way to accomplish this.

This will be a short term form, which is why I'm not terribly worried about "neatness" or polish. I just need it to work, and work quickly.  If you give code snippets, PLEASE give them in context with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved by just clicking on the row to toggle the value.  Not elegant, but works for now